# How to set focus of input in last table row with ng-click function in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm building a task management application and I want the desired behaviour:

- When the user clicks 'Add Task', a new row is added to the table (already done) and the input inside the latest/last table row is focused on.

I don't want it to focus whenever the pages loads, I just want it to focus when a button is clicked with ng-click. I don't know how to achieve this, would anyone be able to offer any help? Would $broadcast and $on be useful here?

Thanks very much.

Comment: If possible then share code..

Comment: This is me asking how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how you are adding new row to table . I am new to Angular so I cant think of a way which will work with `ng-click` since that will call a function in `controller` but it's not recommended to to do DOM manipulation in `controller` so my suggestion would be creating a new custom directive for 'Add Task' button and in that directive adding a `click` listener in link function for the element, which will add a new row to table and focus the input element in it. something like below

```
.directive('myDir', function () {
    return {
         restrict: 'A',
         scope: true,
         link: function (scope, element, attrs) {

            function functionToBeCalled () {
                console.log("It worked!");
            }

            element.on('click', functionToBeCalled);
        }
    };
});
```

you can add your own DOM manipulation code in that `functionToBeCalled` function.
This code is just a basic reference to give you an idea.

feeling lazy so shamelessly copied the `directive` code from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25910678/4587148).